# Dockerfile fails when calling rbenv

Tags: ruby, docker, centos, rbenv, dockerfile

I'm trying to create a Dockerfile that configures my ruby environment. But it is failing when I try to run `docker run -it`

#### Dockerfile

```
FROM centos:6.6

# VOLUME /var/lib/mysql

# ENV HOME /root
# ENV PATH $HOME/.rbenv/bin:$HOME/.rbenv/shims:$PATH
# ENV SHELL /bin/bash

RUN yum update -y
RUN yum install git openssl-devel openssl readline-devel readline zlib-devel zlib libxml2-devel libxml2 libxslt-devel libxslt nginx tar gcc libaio libaio-devel -y
RUN rpm -Uvh https://opscode-omnibus-packages.s3.amazonaws.com/el/6/x86_64/chef-12.5.1-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
RUN yum install -y openssh-server
RUN mkdir -p /var/run/sshd

RUN adduser deploy -p Password1
RUN su - deploy

RUN git clone https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv.git /root/.rbenv
RUN git clone https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build.git /root/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build
RUN ./root/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/install.sh
ENV PATH /root/.rbenv/bin:$PATH
RUN echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> /etc/profile.d/rbenv.sh
RUN echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> .bashrc
RUN echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> $HOME/.bash_profile
RUN source $HOME/.bash_profile
ENV CONFIGURE_OPTS --disable-install-doc

RUN rbenv install 2.2.3
RUN rbenv global 2.2.3
RUN bash -l -c 'gem update --system'
RUN bash -l -c 'gem update'
RUN bash -l -c 'gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries'
RUN bash -l -c 'gem install bundler rails-api --no-rdoc --no-ri'

RUN touch /etc/sysconfig/network

EXPOSE 3306
EXPOSE 22
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 3389
```

#### error

```
Error response from daemon: No command specified
```

Comment: What is the need to run for the container? you have exposed 3306, 22, 80, 3389 ports. I recommend separating your services into other containers. [example](https://github.com/kalelc/docker-to-rails-with-rbenv)

Comment: `Error response from daemon: No command specified` required command. Example `docker run -i -t kalelc/stack ps aux`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at my Dockerfile:

```
FROM centos:6.6

RUN yum update -y
# Install the rbenv and Ruby dependencies
RUN yum install git-core curl zlib1g-dev build-essential libssl-dev libreadline-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev python-software-properties libffi-dev -y
RUN yum install git openssl-devel openssl readline-devel readline zlib-devel zlib libxml2-devel libxml2 libxslt-devel libxslt nginx tar gcc libaio libaio-devel -y
RUN rpm -Uvh https://opscode-omnibus-packages.s3.amazonaws.com/el/6/x86_64/chef-12.5.1-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
RUN yum install -y openssh-server
RUN mkdir -p /var/run/sshd

RUN adduser deploy -p Password1
RUN su - deploy

RUN git clone https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv.git /root/.rbenv
RUN git clone https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build.git /root/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build
RUN ./root/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/install.sh
ENV PATH /root/.rbenv/bin:$PATH
RUN echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> /etc/profile.d/rbenv.sh
RUN echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> .bashrc
RUN echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> $HOME/.bash_profile
RUN source $HOME/.bash_profile
ENV CONFIGURE_OPTS --disable-install-doc

RUN rbenv install 2.2.3
RUN rbenv global 2.2.3
RUN bash -l -c 'gem update --system'
RUN bash -l -c 'gem update'
RUN bash -l -c 'gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries'
RUN bash -l -c 'gem install bundler rails-api --no-rdoc --no-ri'

RUN touch /etc/sysconfig/network

EXPOSE 3306
EXPOSE 22
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 3389
```

Comment: I still get the same error, did you leave out an important part?

Comment: look at my answer. I included ENV statement.

Comment: I've tried that it didn't help. I made some other changes above that did but now I get `Error response from daemon: No command specified` when running `docker run -it `

Comment: listing containers with `docker ps -a` to check your container.To run container execute `docker run -it -image /bin/bash`

Comment: I updated Dockerfile for install rbenv and Ruby dependencies. This solves the problem with rbenv. I tried it and it works :)